# Filter array with recursive function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following json data:

```
[  
   {  
      "product":{  
         "id_product":"1"
      }
      "id_productParent":""
   },
   {  
      "product":{  
         "id_product":"2"
      },
      "id_productParent":"1"
   },
   {  
      "product":{  
         "id_product":"3"
      },
      "id_productParent":"2"
   },
   {  
      "product":{  
         "id_product":"4"
      },
      "id_productParent":"3"
   }
]
```

and I need to return an Array with all the descendant of a product, where the descendant of a product is defined (in pseudocode) like this
`descendant(x) = return (p=> p.id_productParent==x.product + descendant(p))`.

How can I solve this with typescript?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: What have you try ?

Comment: @FahadNisar `descendant(2)` should return products with id `3` and `4`. Note that it has to be recursive. So `descendant(1)` will give products with id 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: If I want to extract the descendants of product 2, the desired output should be 
`[
{  
      "product":{  
         "id_product":"3"
      },
      "id_productParent":"2"
   },
   {  
      "product":{  
         "id_product":"4"
      },
      "id_productParent":"3"
   }
]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with the following solution.
Let `products` and `id` be respectful the array of products and the id of the product for which I want to find his descendants, I filter it like this:

```
...
 this.g = this.products.filter(p => this.isDescendant(p, id));
...
 isDescendant(p, id){
       if(p.id_productParent == id)
        return true;
       if(!p.id_productParent)
         return false;
       return this.isDescendant(this.products.filter(p => p.product.id_product == p.id_productParent)[0], id);

     }
```

Now in `this.g` I have all the descendants of `id`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a baseline for such senario :

```
var g=[  
   {  
      "product":{  
         "id_product":"1"
      },
      "id_productParent":""
   },
   {  
      "product":{  
         "id_product":"2"
      },
      "id_productParent":"1"
   },
   {  
      "product":{  
         "id_product":"3"
      },
      "id_productParent":"2"
   },
   {  
      "product":{  
         "id_product":"4"
      },
      "id_productParent":"2"
   }
]


function eachRecursive(id)
{
  var t=g.filter(i=>i.id_productParent==id);

  if (!t.length) 
  {
    console.log(id)
    return id;
  }
  else

  t.forEach(i=>{
    eachRecursive(i.product.id_product);
  })

}


eachRecursive(2) //3,4
```

Comment: It's a good starting point, but I want to do something like this
`...
var x = 2;
g = g.filter(i => i is not descendant of x);
...
g = g.filter(i=> i is descendant of x)`